# How to make pandas' .plot function to output line graph instead of bar graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make a simple line graph for 3 time-series all in the same graph, I used the following code with the `.plot` function which should show line graph by default. It doesn't and I even specified `kind` as `'line'`, it still shows bar graph instead of line graph.

```
ax = df['total'].plot(title="Sales number", kind='line', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this example should help you to solve the issue:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 10
steps = np.arange(n)
data = pd.DataFrame(index=steps).assign(
    x1=steps + np.random.uniform(size=n),
    x2=steps + np.random.uniform(size=n),
    x3=steps + np.random.uniform(size=n),
)

data.plot.line()
```

The main idea is to set x-axis value as index and select just required columns from the dataset

```py
data.set_index('x_variable')['y1', 'y2', 'y3'].plot.line()
```